# How to scroll up on a terminal opened with vim

Tags: vim

I started to use vim recently, on my workflow I sometimes need to open a file on one side and a terminal on the other.

So while I am editing a file, I use `:vert terminal` then type on it (for example) `git --help`.

But I don't know how to scroll up to see the begining of the return command. How to achieve this?

I tried `Ctrl + j` and other command like that but I don't understand why nothing works

Answer (score 2):

Even when running a terminal, Vim remains true to its modal nature.

You can enter *Terminal-Normal* mode ([`:help Terminal-Normal`](https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html#Terminal-Normal)) using `<C-W> N` (this is a capital 'N' so you have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>) to be able to navigate the terminal window using the regular Vim commands. Entering insert mode will drop you back into the terminal.

The poor man's workaround is to pipe your command through a pager like `git --help|less` as was customary before we had scrolling terminals.